# How to mock a stateful API in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock an interface which has some state, and Python's unittest.mock seems to be designed to make this near impossible.
By stateful I mean that information from the first call (from the code under test) is needed to define the response to subsequent calls. The actual example is an MQTT library wrapper class (which deals with message routing), but that isn't important.

### General background

- The MQTT class is an injected dependency, so I can replace it with a mock object when I construct the object under test. I don't want to do monkey patching.
- I'm going to need this in lots of places in my tests, so I would like something self-contained I can put in a module and import into all the tests which need it. I don't particularly want a solution which relies upon global variables.
- If it makes any difference, the tests are running in pytest.

The class I am trying to mock is `mqtt.Mqtt`. The sequence of calls to it is:

1. Object is constructed, and passed in to the construction of the code under test.
2. `Subscribe()` is called, passing in a callback function as it's second argument. This needs to be stored for later (in the real class, this subscribes to a topic on the MQTT broker).
3. `Publish()` is called (in the real class, this publishes an MQTT message to the broker).
4. Some time passes, then the callback function (the one passed to `Subscribe()`) is called with arguments (in the real class this occurs because an MQTT message was published on the subscribed topic, the arguments are the MQTT payload).

In order to mock this, my basic approach is to:

1. Prepare the response arguments for step 4 in advance.
2. Create the mock object.
3. When `Subscribe()` is called, save the callback function.
4. When `Publish()` is called, check the arguments. If they match, then call the callback function with the prepared arguments.

I'm having huge difficulty finding any relevant examples, and my attempts at implementation crash in all sorts of weird ways.

### Attempt 1 (works, but relies on nonlocal variables and can't easily be made into a library).

```
def test_Mocking1():
    # make a list of messages to be sent back from MQTT
    packed_responses = []
    packed_responses.append("Response1")
    
    # variables for functions below to share
    cached_handler = 0

    def OnMockSubscribe(topic, handler):
        """Method called when Subscribe() is called on mock object"""
        nonlocal cached_handler
        cached_handler = handler

    def OnMockPublish(topic, payload, dummy=None):
        """Method called when Publish() is called on mock object"""
        nonlocal cached_handler
        nonlocal packed_responses

        if topic == "storage/request/test_fooapp_00":
            logger.debug("Will send storage response")
            cached_handler(packed_responses.pop(0))

    attrs = {'Publish.side_effect': OnMockPublish, 'Subscribe.side_effect': OnMockSubscribe}
    # construct a mock object with side effects
    mock_mqtt_client = Mock(spec_set=mqtt.Mqtt, **attrs)

    # now run the test
    thing_to_test = Thing(mock_mqtt_client)
    # thing_to_test will call Subscribe(), then Publish(), then wait for the callback
    thing_to_test.Do()

    # Now assert on the mock to show the correct calls were made.
    mock_mqtt_client.Publish.assert_called_with("storage/request/test_fooapp_00", ANY)
```

This is crude (especially in it's handling of topics) but works - the callback occurs with the correct payload, and the code executes.

### Attempt 1a (works, but same issues)

I managed to replace the explicit construction of the Mock object with a call to create_autospec, which lots of people say gives you instance member functions.

```
    mock_mqtt_client = create_autospec(mqtt.Mqtt, spec_set=True, instance=True, **attrs)
    mock_mqtt_client.Publish.side_effect = OnMockPublish
    mock_mqtt_client.Subscribe.side_effect = OnMockSubscribe
```

But using this code still requires the nonlocal variables and free functions to make it work (no mock object scope available).

### Attempt 2 (dies after 12 seconds with 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object').

The logic here is to create a class which derives from Mock in order to put the various moving parts into the class, particularly the cached callback function.

```
class MockedMqtt(Mock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # add to the argument list
        kwargs['spec'] = mqtt.Mqtt
        # call parent class constructor
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._cached_handler = 0
        self._responses_ = []

        self.Publish.side_effect = self.OnMockPublish
        self.Subscribe.side_effect = self.OnMockSubscribe

    def SetResponses(self, responses):
        self._responses_ = responses

    def OnMockSubscribe(self, topic, handler):
        """Method called when Subscribe() is called on mock object"""
        self._cached_handler = handler

    def OnMockPublish(self, topic, payload, dummy=None):
        """Method called when Publish() is called on mock object"""

        if topic == "storage/request/test_fooapp_00":
            self._cached_handler(self._responses_.pop(0))

def test_Mocking2():
    # make a list of messages to be sent back from MQTT
    packed_responses = []
    packed_responses.append("Response1")

    # construct a mock object with side effects
    mock_mqtt_client = MockedMqtt()
    mock_mqtt_client.SetResponses(packed_responses)

    # now run the test
    thing_to_test = Thing(mock_mqtt_client)
    # thing_to_test will call Subscribe(), then Publish(), then wait for the callback
    thing_to_test.Do()

    # Now assert on the mock to show the correct calls were made.
    mock_mqtt_client.Publish.assert_called_with("storage/request/test_fooapp_00", ANY)
```

This one fails with a monumental traceback, but the last part looks like:

```
tests/impedance_calculation_test.py:29: in __init__
    self.Publish.side_effect = self.OnMockPublish
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:648: in __getattr__
    result = self._get_child_mock(
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1019: in _get_child_mock
    return klass(**kw)
tests/impedance_calculation_test.py:29: in __init__
    self.Publish.side_effect = self.OnMockPublish
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:648: in __getattr__
    result = self._get_child_mock(
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1019: in _get_child_mock
    return klass(**kw)
tests/impedance_calculation_test.py:29: in __init__
    self.Publish.side_effect = self.OnMockPublish
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:648: in __getattr__
    result = self._get_child_mock(
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1019: in _get_child_mock
    return klass(**kw)
tests/impedance_calculation_test.py:25: in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1075: in __init__
    _safe_super(CallableMixin, self).__init__(
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:437: in __init__
    self._mock_add_spec(spec, spec_set, _spec_as_instance, _eat_self)
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:500: in _mock_add_spec
    res = _get_signature_object(spec,
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:107: in _get_signature_object
    return func, inspect.signature(sig_func)
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:3130: in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:2879: in from_callable
    return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:2338: in _signature_from_callable
    wrapped_sig = _signature_from_callable(
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:2330: in _signature_from_callable
    return _signature_from_function(sigcls, obj,
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:2194: in _signature_from_function
    parameters.append(Parameter(name, annotation=annotation,
/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py:2517: in __init__
    self._kind = _ParameterKind(kind)
/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py:384: in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

cls = <enum '_ParameterKind'>, value = <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>

    def __new__(cls, value):
        # all enum instances are actually created during class construction
        # without calling this method; this method is called by the metaclass'
        # __call__ (i.e. Color(3) ), and by pickle
>       if type(value) is cls:
E       RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py:674: RecursionError
```

The loop appears to be at the end of my `__init__()` method where I try to attach methods of the class as side effects. My best guess is that this is instead causing the Mock object to create more mocks, which get stuck in an infinitely recursing `__init__()`.

Other than rolling my own completely (create a class, implement all the necessary methods, do my own storing of the call history and so on), I'm not sure where to go next with this? It doesn't seem like this should be hard to do (and it wouldn't be in C++ / trompeloeil).

Comment: _"Other than rolling my own completely"_ - I'm not sure why you'd want to rule that out, it's not a complicated interface to implement.

Comment: Only because I would have to replicate all the call counting, assertions etc. features of Mock from scratch (that was the idea of extending the existing Mock class).